# Get client username who is accessing the application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have created one asp.net application and in that i have written the following code to get the username

```
 string username=  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() ;
```

It is working for before i hosted my application in IIS

After hosting the application in IIS it is still showing username as my username only..

But i need the username of client who is accessing the application

No authentication is required to access my  application ..Anybody can able access my application and i need to fetch username of client

Is there any way to achieve this ??

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean it's returning your username even when someone else accesses your site over the internet ?

Answer (score 0):

If application does not required authentication (the mode attribute of the authentication element is not set or is set to None in the web.config file)

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

and anonymous access is enabled in IIS (by default), the HttpContext.User property returns a default anonymous principal, which is one for all users.

To get the name of each user you need to implement one of authentication schemes - Windows, Forms or Passport. For example, to get a Windows account name of the user on the intranet site you need to set authentication mode to Windows, and set IIS authentication to Integration Windows Authentication (and disable Anonymous Authentication) and then use the User.Identity.Name.